# I want to install the mo curve editor in angular 2 , anybody knows how?

Tags: css, angular, animation

I'm using the [mo.js](http://mojs.io/)  library to do animations and there is an editor to create easing paths, when I try to implement the constructor to create the [curve editor](https://github.com/legomushroom/mojs-curve-editor) I get this error

```
**__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_mojs_curve_editor__ is not a constructor**
```

here are my imports

```
import * as mojs from 'mo-js';
import * as MojsCurveEditor from 'mojs-curve-editor';

  constructor() {
  const mojsCurve = new MojsCurveEditor({ name: 'logo scale', isSaveState: true });
```

then I get the error but if i called the same function in the console on dev-tools then it creates the editor with out errors

Please any help to make it work in angular4 would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```
const mojsCurve = new MojsCurveEditor.MojsCurveEditor({ name: 'logo scale', isSaveState: true });
```

but this implies that the third party library is correctly imported in vendor.ts file

Comment: I tried that but is not working in my angular cli project @sancelot